# Force text to wrap

Tags: css

This is my website's main menu:

[image]

As you you'll notice, the text inside main menu's items isn't wrapping. I've tried many solutions suggested but nothing seems to affect these items. Here's the css code:

```
#pt_custommenu .parentMenu a{
    width: 100px; height: 59px;
    line-height: normal;
    padding-top: 0; padding-bottom:0; 
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: none;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

I'd like to make text break into two lines, like it would normally do, since the `<a>` element has a standard width and height.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider adding a partial snapshot of your website page to this question rather than a link, so it will be useful for future reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `&nbsp;`

This code inserts a space **without wrap**. Normal spaces don't do that.

You can retrieve more info about here: 
http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/www_faq/nbsp.html

EDIT: I'm going to copy the relevant info in case this link someday dissappears:

> `&nbsp;` is the entity used to represent a non-breaking space. It is
>   essentially a standard space, the primary difference being that a
>   browser should not break (or wrap) a line of text at the point that
>   this   occupies.
>
> Many WYSIWYG HTML editors insert these   entities in an effort to
>   control the layout of the HTML document. For example, such an editor
>   may use a series of non-breaking spaces to indent a paragraph like
>   this:
>
> ```
> <p>
>     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; This first line of text is supposed to be indented. However, many browsers will not render it as intended.
> </p>
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> There are some times when it is "acceptable" or "advisable" to use the
>     entity so long as the consequences are understood:
>
> Its intended use of creating a space between words or elements that
>   should not be broken. The only problems that can be associated with
>   this use is that too many words strung together with non-breaking
>   spaces may require some graphical browsers to show horizontal
>   scrollbars or cause them to display the text overlapping table
>   borders.

Comment: That's interesting (and weird!) but I can't see any '&nbsp;' inside menu items. There are just normal spaces there. (checked it using firebug ad firefox code view)

Comment: @ktsixit Edit the span element as HTML, you'll notice it looks like: `<span>Machinery&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Components</span>`

Comment: It's visible only using Chrome's Developer Tools. You're right. The item's content comes from database (this is a magento e-shop). Let me check how it's stored in there.

Comment: I checked database and... I have no idea where they come from, they're not visible in phpmyadmin anyway. I just used php str_replace to replace them with normal spaces. Thank's a lot for your help, I could never find this my self...

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to help :) It's very difficult to notice the issue if the content is delivered from DB.

Answer (score 5):

You want text to be broken so use following:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

I checked again and saw you didn't use any spaces, thats why it can't. Replace `&nbsp;` with normal space character. Otherwise browser will read it as a block without spaces.

Comment: I've tried that but it makes words split in half. I'd like to have line breaks only in 'spaces'.